# Facebook Graph-API Like a Page with Auth Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I read through the facebook refence-api-documentatons and the facebook permission-api very precise, but the following doesn't work:

```
curl -F "access_token=$access_token" https://graph.facebook.com/$APP_ID/likes
```

where $access_token is a token with the permissions: email,publish_stream,user_likes

I get the error:

> "error":{"message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to
>   make this API call.","type":"OAuthException"

What is wrong?

On the graph-api-refence-site is written:

You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes connection by posting to graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments and graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes, respectively:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' http://graph.facebook.com/313449204401/likes
```